# Gracefully update running celery pod in Kubernetes

Tags: celery, kubernetes, celerybeat

I have a Kubernetes cluster running Django, Celery, RabbitMq and Celery Beat.  I have several periodic tasks spaced out throughout the day (so as to keep server load down).  There are only a few hours when no tasks are running, and I want to limit my rolling-updates to those times, without having to track it manually.  So I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to fire off a script or task of some sort that will monitor the Celery server, and trigger a rolling update once there's a window in which no tasks are actively running.  There are two possible ways I thought of doing this, but I'm not sure which is best, nor how to implement either one.

- Run a script (bash or otherwise) that checks up on the Celery server every few minutes, and initiates the rolling-update if the server is inactive
- Increment the celery app name before each update (in the Beat run command, the Celery run command, and in the celery.py config file), create a new Celery pod, rolling-update the Beat pod, and then delete the old Celery 12 hours later (a reasonable time span for all running tasks to finish)

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you control when the tasks are running? Why do you need to do a rolling update if you're waiting for a time when the service is unused?

Comment: I control when the tasks start, but not how long they'll run, and I don't want all of them to run at the same time, both for server load purposes and because some of them may be inserting large batches of records into the database at the same time, which has caused record id conflicts in the past. As for the rolling update itself, the need arises whenever I want to update the server code, which does happen on nearly a weekly basis.

Comment: I meant that if you only update when no tasks are running, do you need a rolling update instead of an immediate (non-rolling) update?

Comment: I don't see your point.  The alternative to rolling update is to delete the rc and recreate it with the new image, right?  That doesn't help me any.  The method is unimportant, the goal is to update the server code without stopping a running task.